# MUI: BottomNavigationAction override label styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm implementing a `BottomNavigation` bar for mobile. I want the label texts to be UPPERCASE and add 5px to spacing to icon above.

```
<BottomNavigation 
  value={selectedTab} 
  onChange={this.handleTabChange} 
  className={classes.bottomNav}>
  <BottomNavigationAction 
    label="Details" 
    value={0} 
    icon={<DescriptionIcon />} 
    className={classes.bottomNavLabel} 
  />
  <BottomNavigationAction
    label="Card"
    value={1}
    icon={<CreditCardIcon />}
    disabled={!navEnabled}
    className={classes.bottomNavLabel}
  />
</BottomNavigation>
```

My styles look like this:

```
export default ({ spacing, breakpoints }: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    bottomNav: {
      position: 'fixed',
      bottom: 0,
      width: '100%',
    },
    bottomNavLabel: {
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      marginTop: 5,
    },
  })
```

I tried styling in `bottomNavLabel` class but it's hitting the whole button element. I only want to hit the `<span>` element with the label inside.

According to [docs i can override `classes.label`](https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/) but I can't get it to work. I suspect this means I create a wrapper component around  `BottomNavigationAction` but I would prefer not to do this, as I'm not using this elsewhere and it feels kind of "bloated" to do.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. `<BottomNavigationAction>` takes a prop `classes` where I define the `label` styling. Like this:

```
<BottomNavigation 
  value={selectedTab} 
  onChange={this.handleTabChange} 
  className={classes.bottomNav}>
  <BottomNavigationAction 
    label={<span className="bottomNavLabel">Details</span>} 
    value={0} 
    icon={<DescriptionIcon />}
    classes={{label: classes.label}}
  />
  <BottomNavigationAction
    label={<span className="bottomNavLabel">Card</span>} 
    value={1}
    icon={<CreditCardIcon />}
    disabled={!navEnabled}
    classes={{label: classes.label}}
  />
</BottomNavigation>
```

And styling:

```
export default ({ spacing, breakpoints }: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    bottomNav: {
      position: 'fixed',
      bottom: 0,
      width: '100%',
    },
    label: {
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      marginTop: 5,
    },
  })
```